# ExpandableListView inside ScrollView is showing only one item

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-scrollview

When I use ExpandableListView inside ScrollView it will show only one item,It is not showing all items and also when selected items it will shows all child items.

Comment: edit your code here.

Comment: Lists are already scrollable. Get rid of the ScrollView

Comment: Have you try to use NestedScrollView ? Ref : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your parent layout contains more items. Then you have to fix the height of  listview in form of some dp instead of wrap_content/match_parent, or use NestedScrollView.